# Why is the computation of the Jacobian determinant different for certain integrations?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, determinant, surface-integrals

I am used to computing the Jacobian, when, say, changing from x,y coordinates to u,v coordinates, as computing the determinant of the derivative matrix of $x_u$,$x_v$, $y_u$, $y_v$, i.e., differentiating with respect to the new variables.

But I recently computed the Jacobian for a surface integral, and it is the magnitude of the cross-product of two partial derivative vectors, which gives the area of a parallelogram spanned by the two vectors -- makes perfect sense, intuitively.

But, why the difference in algorithm?  Is the second way of computing the Jacobian ...strictly for surface integrals?

Thanks,

Comment: They're really the same computation.  Both the Jacobian and the magnitude of the cross-product give the necessary "are of a parallelogram".

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, what if one of three variables is fixed, say the radius is fixed at r = 1, and I then parametrize the unit sphere, centered at (0,0,0), as U = (cos$\theta$sin$\phi$,sin$\theta$sin$\phi$,cos$\phi$)?  Going through the partial derivative computations to come up with a 3x3 matrix to take the determinant of, I would get a column of zeros, when differentiating with respect to r.  Then the determinant is zero, and makes the Jacobian zero...

Comment: It's a double integral, not a triple integral.  You should be taking the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Comment: hmm...@Omnomnomnom, then computing the determinant of the matrix $x_\theta$, $x_\phi$, $y_\theta$, $y_\phi$, gives me $sin(\phi)$$cos(\phi)$, while the computation of the magnitude of the cross product gives the correct Jacobian of $sin(\phi)$ ...

Comment: yea, @Omnomnomnom, I just computed the magnitude of the cross product again and got the correct value of sin$(\phi)$, so I'm not sure why there's a discrepancy.  and i'm pretty sure I've computed all of the partial derivatives correctly for the first method of computing the Jacobian, but it gives me an extra factor of $cos(\phi)$